# How to change a value of <p> element from a php page

Tags: php, forms

I have created a login form like below:

```
<form name="form1">

    <input type="text" name="myusername" >

    <input type="password" name="mypassword" >

    <input type="submenter code hereit" name="submit">

    <p name="massage"></p>

</form>
```

It will send input details to checkdata its a php file
if match then show login else echo "wrong username and password"
so problem is that i want this massage in `<p name="massage">` element. Please Help!

Comment: For print message php message in html tag use                                         '<p name="massage"><?php echo 'any message'; ?> </p>'

Comment: First please your whole code then we can help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First rename `index.html` to `index.php` then do as following:

**checkdata.php**

```
if($username=='right' && $password=='right')
    $msg='right username and password';
else{
    $msg='wrong username and password';
}
header('Location: index.php?msg='.$msg);
```

**index.php**

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg']!="") { ?>
    <p name="massage"><?php echo $_GET['msg']; ?> </p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: OK, you want to send the message between pages. Then i would start a session, store the message (and all your other messages), then show it on the other page:

```
//login.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = "wrong login";
```

Form page

```
<? session_start(); ?>
<p name="massage"><?=$_SESSION['message']?></p>
```

Comment: thanks but login details are checked in checklogin.php and  i want massage in index.html so please explane how to do

Answer (score 0):

For print message php message in html tag use

```
$msg='';
if($username=='right' && $password=='right')
$msg='right username and password';
else{
$msg='wrong username and password';

}
<p name="massage"><?php echo $msg; ?> </p>
```

Comment: thanks i am tryiing this code

Comment: check this link for your reference since you are beginner:http://www.w3schools.in/php/php-login-without-using-database/

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **Session** for it.
For example, your checklogin.php will look like

```
$username = $_REQUEST['myusername'];
$password = $_REQUEST['mypassword'];

$qry = mysql_query("select * from table_users where username = '$username' and password = '$password' ");
if($qry && mysql_num_rows($qry) == 1)
{
      header('location: dashborad.php');
}
else
{
     $_SESSION['msg'] = 'something went wrong';
     header('location: index.html');
}
```

Then in index file, you can check like this,

```
<p name="massage">
<?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['msg']) && $_SESSION['msg'] != '')
       {
            echo $_SESSION['msg'];
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '';
       }
?>
</p>
```

Don't forget to include **session_start();** at the beginning of both files.